# A String Challenge

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, domdocument

i have a string that contains HTML structure :

```
<p> ... </p>
<p> .... <a> .... </a></p>
<div id="quick_preview">
<p> .... </p>
</div>
<p> ... </p>
```

and what i want to do is just inject a `<description>` tag in `div` with class `quick_preview` after `p` tag. something like this :

```
<p> ... </p>
<p> .... <a> .... </a></p>
<div id="quick_preview">
  <description>
    <p> .... </p>
  </description>
</div>
<p> ... </p>
```

i use lots of techniques ,like domdocument or string processing, but can't find the right solution.

Comment: `DOMDocument` along with `DOMXPath` will do this in a jiffy. Have you tried it?

Comment: Humm , nope ! is domxpath can load html stream ? i just try domdocument

Comment: if you have access to the functions where the string is assembled, I would make the change there

Comment: no , i can't do that , i have just access to Database nothing anymore ...

Comment: @jon can you show me a sample ?

Comment: @bizzare: I can search SO and/or Google to find one, but you can do the same yourself.

Comment: @Jon yep ! i find some solution ... i just thank you by accepting your answer !! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough example that should help you get started using [PHP's DOM functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). The example will need to be expanded to check for errors and such, but it does work.

```
$ php test.php 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><p>First p</p><p>Another p<a>a link</a></p><div id="quick_preview"><description><p>Third p </p></description></div><p>Last p</p></root>
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$xml = "<root><p>First p</p><p>Another p<a>a link</a></p><div id='quick_preview'><p>Third p </p></div><p>Last p</p></root>";

$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = '//div';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

$entry = $entries->item(0);

$new = $doc->createElement("description");
$new->appendChild($entry->firstChild);
$entry->appendChild($new);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```